# Is there a way to remove the artist name from a large number of titles in itunes?

Tags: itunes, music, macos

I have a few hundred mp3's which are labeled, e.g., "Rush - 01 - actual title of song". Is there a way to automatically remove "Rush - XX - " form the title names?

Answer (score 2):

Try Doug's AppleScripts for iTunes . I think [This one does it](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/ss.php?sp=tagsmirrorartalbfnom) if not there will be something similar

Answer (score 0):

On the payware  (but excellent) side, you have [Song Genie](http://www.equinux.com/us/products/songgenie/index.html) which will do all that for you.

Answer (score 0):

[MusicBrainz Picard](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Picard) can do file renaming and/or moving as it tags.

Answer (score 0):

if you want pay some you can use [Tune UP](http://www.tuneupmedia.com/index.php) it's also compatible with iTunes.
and other choice for you is to use [jaikoz](http://www.jthink.net/jaikoz/).

Answer (score 0):

[A Better Finder Rename](http://www.publicspace.net/ABetterFinderRename/index.html) is a commercial product (US $20) that can, among many other features, batch-modify ID3 tags in your iTunes files. You can download a trial version and try it on a few files.

Answer (score 0):

Another option might have been to use [TriTag](http://www.feedface.com/projects/tritag.html) to assign new titles based on the names of the files.

Or run a temporary script like this in AppleScript Editor:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    repeat with t in selection
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to " - "
        set name of t to text item 3 of (get name of t)
    end repeat
end tell
```